# What does the phrase "class object" refer to in the context of thread synchronization?

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm new to Java and is trying to learn the concept of synchronisation.  I saw this quote from Java Tutorial Oracle. I am struggling to understand what they are referring to by the phrase "Class object". What exactly is a class object?

> You might wonder what happens when a static synchronized method is
>   invoked, since a static method is associated with a class, not an
>   object. In this case, the thread acquires the intrinsic lock for the
>   Class object associated with the class. Thus access to class's static
>   fields is controlled by a lock that's distinct from the lock for any
>   instance of the class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Class<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) is a class itself. You can get class instances by:

- Calling e.g. `String.class` (if you know the class statically), which is an instance of `Class<String>`
- Calling `someInstance.getClass()` (if you want the concrete class of an instance), which is an instance of `Class<? extends SomeInstance>`, assuming that `someInstance` is a reference of type `SomeInstance` (the bound comes because it might be a subclass of `SomeInstance`).

Answer (score 1):

`Class` is an actual class in Java. There exist objects of type `Class`. With each keyword-`class` will be associated one object of type `Class` (at least I assume - this makes sense and makes that block make sense).

I think the behavior makes sense - when you synchronize a static method, you certainly can't synchronize with respect to any object.

Arguably `synchronized static` is an antipattern. It's a program-wide bottleneck and anathema to scaleability. Say your program works well on a 1 GB server. If you want to adapt it to an 8 GB server with 256x the ports and network capacity and 8x the cores, there's *no way* to scale up the synchronized static code. You can't create another object, of course. I think the only solution is to spin up another process and another JVM with it.